# Update users when relevent button is clicked

Tags: php, html

[image: user table]

i have designed the above table using php and html. what i want to do is update the row of the relevant user when the respective update button is clicked. 
this how the table is created

```
   <tr class="<?php if(isset($classname)) echo $classname;?>">
<td><input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="<?php echo $row["NIC_NO"]; ?>" ></td>

<td><?php echo $row["USERNAME"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["ADMIN"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["NIC_NO"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["EB"]; ?></td>
<td><input type="button" name="<?php echo $row["NIC_NO"]; ?>" value="Update" onClick="setUpdateAction();" /></td>
</tr>
```

How do i take the value from the respective update button and write the sql code only to update the particular row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML :

```
<tr class="<?php if(isset($classname)) echo $classname;?>" data-id="<?= $row["NIC_NO"]; ?>">
<td><input type="checkbox" name="users[]" value="<?php echo $row["NIC_NO"]; ?>" ></td>

<td><?php echo $row["USERNAME"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["ADMIN"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["NIC_NO"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["EB"]; ?></td>
<td><input type="button" data-id="<?= $row["NIC_NO"]; ?>" data-do="update"/></td>
</tr>
```

In your JS (with jQuery) :

```
$("[data-do='update']").click(function(){
    var instance = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"update.php",
        data:"id="+instance.attr('data-id'),
        success:function(response){
            trObject = $('tr[data-id="'+instance.attr('data-id')+'"]');
            tdObjects = trObject.find("td");
            tdObjects[1].html(response.USERNAME);
            tdObjects[2].html(response.ADMIN);
            tdObjects[3].html(response.NIC_NO);
            tdObjects[4].html(response.EB);
        }
    });
});
```

In your update.php

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE NIC_NO = ?');
$stmt->execute(array($id));
$data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
<td><input type="button" name="NIC_CO" value="<?php echo $row["NIC_NO"]; ?>" onClick="setUpdateAction();" /></td>
```

The name is acessible on the server side, so you'd get:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST["NIC_CO"]))
    $to_update = $_REQUEST["NIC_CO"];
```